# Understanding two declined flags

Tags: discussion, flagging

My flag on the comment of this [answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/4390/3260) was declined. It's a standard comment to remind OP to accept an answer. I think we can remove these comments after a while if the answer is indeed accepted. But the flag "**It's no longer needed**" has been declined and I would like to understand why.

In this [question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6722/3260), I flagged two comments, one has been transferred to an answer, and the other is a suggestion to write the first comment has an answer. I also thought they both could be flagged as "**It's no longer needed**" but one as been declined, and the other, for some mysterious reason is still pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reexamined the flags and agree with both of your points. I'm not sure why they were initially declined, but they have now been deleted.